# EF Code First migrations - how to add seed to my migration?

Tags: entity-framework, migration

I already have few migrations, and now I am adding another migration, but this time I want to add seed to it. I tried adding this near my Up() and Down() methods:

```
protected override void Seed(ScykDb context)
{
}
```

But my compiler says I cannot do that. How can I add seed to my migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed is not available per migration, only at the `DbContext` level.

You can easily get around it by adding a call to `Sql()` in your `Up()` method:

```
Sql("insert into ponies (col1, col2.....");
```